# Reading Web Json with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I will like to read a JSON file (kind of like a webservice running on a server) and process it using JavaScript.

I was wondering if anyone will be able to point me to some good example, tutorials or sample code?

Much appreciated.

Comment: google has some good examples. what have you tried? has it worked?

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: The answers I found on Google all lead to parsing a JSON string in a var. But what if my var is a URI?

Eg. var JSON_URL = "http://abc.com/data.json"

Comment: This are two independent problems: Getting the data and parsing it. You have to Ajax to load the JSON file. If file is from an external domain, you have to use a proxy or JSONP if supported by the server (but that's not JSON anymore, despite its name).

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's `$.getJSON` function. See the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question entirely, but if you have a string accessible in your JS, you can call `JSON.parse(yourString)` which will return a JS object representation of the string. This should work in all modern browsers.

Comment: Nope. I am looking to do a JSON.parse(URI).
Eg. var JSON_URL = "http://abc.com/data.json"

Comment: Ah, gotcha. In this case, you can do as Felix commented above on your initial question -- make an AJAX request to your server, read the text response and then call JSON.parse. If this is not your server, then you may have cross-domain issues -- can you clarify your use case a little bit more?